# Openjson expression sql 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, json, sql-server-2016

Is there any way where you can specify the path as variable in open json like the below?

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)

 set @JSON = '{ "amounts": [
    {
      "Charge_Id": "368",
      "Amount": "800",
      "FineType_Id": 3,
      "user_id": 2
    },
    {
      "Charge_Id": "368",
      "Amount": "600",
      "FineType_Id": 4,
      "user_id": 2
    }
  ]

  }';


DECLARE @counter int
DECLARE @expression NVARCHAR(50)
set @counter = 0
set @expression = ‘$.amounts[‘+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),@counter)+’]’

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON,@expression)
WITH(Charge_Id int, Amount money, FineType_Id int, user_id int)AS JSON
```

Since this causes an error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31 Incorrect syntax near
>   '@expression'. Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 32 Incorrect syntax
>   near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table
>   expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context
>   clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

[It looks like the compatibility level doesn't match with SQL 2016](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level.). You need to check and change this. To [view or change your compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database):

> 1. After connecting to the appropriate instance of the SQL Server Database Engine, in Object Explorer, click the server name.
> 2. Expand Databases, and, depending on the database, either select a user database or expand System Databases and select a system database.
> 3. Right-click the database, and then click Properties.
>
>    The Database Properties dialog box opens.
>
>    In the Select a page pane, click Options.
> 4. The current compatibility level is displayed in the Compatibility level list box.
> 5. To change the compatibility level, select a different option from the list. The choices are SQL Server 2008 (100), SQL Server 2012 (110), SQL Server 2014 (120), SQL Server 2016 (130), and SQL Server 2017 (140).